# Is there a way to take a screenshot as bytes (Fedora 35)

Tags: python, linux, screenshot, fedora-35

I'm trying to find a way to take a screenshot and save it as bytes like in this video: https://youtu.be/WymCpVUPWQ4 where he uses win32ui in Python to do that.

I've searched around and haven't found anyome who has answered this.

I've done this before in windows where I've screenshot as bytes, read as numpy, pass it into opencv and basically have the viewer open refreshing the image between 30-60fps.

Any leads would be great.

Comment: windows or fedora? decide. -- please take the [tour], then review [ask] and [help/on-topic]

Comment: Have you already checked [mss](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54540993/18667225)?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I thought tagging fedora-35 was what I had to do. I'll edit my question to include f35.

Comment: @Markus Thanks! It does exactly what I need it to do. Thanks for the lead.

Comment: language tag wasn't there either. I've added `python`. -- the "fedora-35" tag is very useless because nobody even watches that tag. if you want eyes on your question, use (suitable) tags that aren't so terribly specific as _that exact version number of that specific linux distro_

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks I do that for future questions.

Answer (score 0):

Python has a library called mss that does whats required: https://github.com/BoboTiG/python-mss